# Use custom template with Essential Grid

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Using [Essential Grid plugin](https://www.themepunch.com/essgrid-doc/essential-grid-documentation/) for WordPress theme development, I've created a masonry layout with cards which display all the post. Each card has an image, title, and so forth. With shortcodes, I've been able to add the same masonry layout found on the homepage to the post page. I've created a custom template for the post content. However, my custom template shows as the first post(which I want), but the other cards which are in the masonry layout are below it. I'm trying to have it float next to each other.

Desired layout: 1 being my custom card template

```
1-2-3-4-5-6-7
8-9-etc..
```

Current Layout:

```
1
2-3-4-5-6-7
```

For better reference, I'm trying to achieve [this type of layout](https://foodgawker.com/post/2017/12/08/701609/) using the [Essential Grid plugin](https://www.themepunch.com/essgrid-doc/essential-grid-documentation/) for WordPress.

Comment: Can you please share URL? I think with minor change you can achieve it. Something in your CSS is preventing that

Comment: I know this limits the help I can receive, however, I've asked the client for permission to share and was asked not too.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way these days for this would be flexbox, check out this article:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

You need to apply `display: flex;` to the wrapper and `flex-wrap: wrap;`, in article You can find more details on how to manipulate alignments for best-looking results.

Comment: Yes, that is an option but in doing so, I have to change a lot of CSS for the masonry grid... which is not ideal... for now. Thank you for your input.